# Nested list won't copy without assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, copy

I want to copy a list and make changes to the copy without affecting the original list.

```
a = [[2,3],[4,5]]
b = list(a)

print(b)

del b[0][0]

print(b)
print(a)
```

I was expecting `a = [[2, 3], [4, 5]]` in the end.

However, the output was

```
[[2, 3], [4, 5]]
[[3], [4, 5]]
[[3], [4, 5]]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need a nested copy e.g. `b = [l[:] for l in a]`

Comment: A deep copy is best: `import copy; b = copy.deepcopy(a)`

Comment: You are making changes not to the list you copied, but to the list *inside* the list you copied, and since you didn't copy those elements (i.e. `list(a)` creates a *shallow* copy), then of course, those changes are reflected in your copy.